# Delete an element from torch.Tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I'm trying to delete an item from a tensor.

In the example below, How can I remove the third item from the tensor ?

```
tensor([[-5.1949, -6.2621, -6.2051, -5.8983, -6.3586, -6.2434, -5.8923, -6.1901,
         -6.5713, -6.2396, -6.1227, -6.4196, -3.4311, -6.8903, -6.1248, -6.3813,
         -6.0152, -6.7449, -6.0523, -6.4341, -6.8579, -6.1961, -6.5564, -6.6520,
         -5.9976, -6.3637, -5.7560, -6.7946, -5.4101, -6.1310, -3.3249, -6.4584,
         -6.2202, -6.3663, -6.9293, -6.9262]], grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward1>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first filter array through indices and then concat both

```
t.shape
torch.Size([1, 36])

t = torch.cat((t[:,:3], t[:,4:]), axis = 1)

t.shape
torch.Size([1, 35])
```

Answer (score 7):

I think that doing this with indexing is more readable.

```
t[t!=t[0,3]]
```

The result is the same as with the `cat` solution from below.

**BE CAREFUL**: This will usually work for floats, but beware that if the value at `[0,3]` occurs more than once in the array, you will remove **all occurrences** of this item.

Answer (score 4):

You can use numpy`s [r_](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) indexing trick

```py
y = x[:, np.r_[:3, 4:36]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to remove multiple elements by index you could do the following.

```
# Removing elements
x = torch.arange(10)
y = torch.arange(4)*2
print(x)
print(y)
x[y] = -1
print(x[x != -1])
```

This gives output

```
tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
tensor([0, 2, 4, 6])
tensor([1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9])
```